# How do i customise the android toolbar shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am newbie in android app developing and learning android UI design.I am trying to make a toolbar like below image.But i don't now what is the xml code for below image toolbar. [image: toolbar example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options. Personally I'd go for the first.

### Overriding the view

First approach is overriding the default toolbar / action bar. This has the advantage of being able to use AndroidX navigation, automatic back stack navigation, etc, with the disadvantage of a bit less control.

All you need to do is enable custom views on your action bar, apply a custom view, hide the default title, then set the elevation to 0 so there's no shadow. This will be something like:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.elevation = 0f;
```

`R.layout.your_custom_layout` can then be whatever layout you want, so long as it fits in the same space. I've [written a full tutorial on this previously](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/creating-a-custom-android-actionbar/), as well as a [sample project](https://github.com/JakeSteam/BlogCustomActionBar) in Kotlin.

### Defining your own

The second approach is ignoring the built in toolbar / action bar, and just rolling your own. This gives you full control, and allows setting the bar to any height, but you lose all built in functionality. For this, just use themes without a toolbar, and draw your own bar (perhaps in an activity that then swaps in fragments).